# Condition Operator and the std::cout not playing nice

Tags: c++, c++11, cout, conditional-operator

I am learning about the condition operator using the book "C++ Primer 5th edition" I am currently attempting Exercise 4.21 in chapter 4. The exercise reads as follows:

Exercise 4.21: Write a program to use a conditional operator to find the elements in `vector<int>` that have odd value and double the value of each such element.

I have used a condition operator in a ranged for to process each element in the vector "ivec". The issue/error occurs in the "else" ( : ) portion of the condition operator when I try to `std::cout << &ivec << " holds an even number";` This code is supposed to print out the address in memory and state that it holds an even number. However I get the below error.

Error received: Cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function. the error is refering to the `std::cout` on line 15.

Compiler used : VB express 2013

1) Can anyone explain why my code is in error?

2) How can I change the code to correct the error and get the program to work?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
int i1;
std::vector<int> ivec;

while (std::cin >> i1){ ivec.push_back(i1); };

for (int p1 : ivec){
    int i2 = p1 % 2;
    (i2 != 0) ? p1 *= 2 : std::cout << &ivec << " holds an even number";
    i2 = 0;
}   

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: From my experience, VisualStudio (which I suppose you mean with "VB express 2013") does not have nice understandable error messages. Maybe you should try clang++ instead, for example [as an online compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9628bf94a6ba3a14).

Comment: So, the parts after `?` and `:` need to be the same type or implicitly convertible into the same type, since the expression `(a?b:c)` needs to evaluate to one type. Your types are `int` and `std::ostream &` which are not convertible into each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional operator should not be treated as an if/else statement. It is not that. It is an expression, with a value. As such, it has a type. That type is determined by the second and third sub-expressions (before and after the colon). They need to be convertible to a common type.

In your case:

```
(i2 != 0) ? p1 *= 2 : std::cout << &ivec << " holds an even number";
```

To the left of the colon, you have an `int` (p1). And on the right, you have an `std::ostream` (cout). These are not convertible to a common type. That is the source of your error. What your book is wanting is probably more along the lines of something like this:

```
bool is_odd = p1 % 2 == 1;
p1 *= (is_odd) ? 2 : 1;
```

Here, we are multiplying `p1` by the value of the expression `(is_odd) ? 2 : 1` -- And the type of that expression is `int` (since both `1` and `2` are type `int`).

Note that for this to have the intended effect, you need to make `p1` a reference, otherwise you are not having an effect on the element in the vector.